# How can I prevent my ASP.NET page from reloading when a button is pressed, while still enabling the button event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

At the moment I've got several buttons that update labels when pressed, but I'd like to keep everything else - some other web controls and a table - present on the page, exactly as they are. I attempted to force this by doing:

```
                TableCell addButtonCell = new TableCell();
                Button addButton = new Button();
                addButton.Text = "Add";
                addButton.OnClientClick = "return false;"; // < this
                addButton.Click += new EventHandler(addButton_Click);
                addButtonCell.Controls.Add(addButton);
```

But now my actual button event won't fire.

Comment: Please show the code for the OnClientClick button.

Comment: This line addButton.OnClientClick = "return false;"; will prevent the server onclick event to be fired.

Comment: I suggest you use updatepanel to refresh only certain parts of your page.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish with this. OnClick server event requires to call onclick using javascript. If you disable it with "OnClientClick", when do you expect to raise the click event?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Add" OnClientClick="click(); return false;"  />

<script>
function click(){
    alert("Hey, it's not a postback!");
}
</script>
```

Above example shows how you can interact with the button just on the client side. The key here is to add `return false;` statement so that a postback will not be issued. So no page reload would occur in this case.

Depending on your requirement, you need to understand - should button click be handled on the client side or server side? What is it you want to achieve after button is clicked?

If you prefer handling on the server side without having page reloaded on every click, you can try `UpdatePanel` control, which allows you to perform partial-page update.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Add" OnClick="addButton_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please refer to this MSDN article for more details about UpdatePanel control.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx